# PhpStorm warnings with jQuery parameters

Tags: jquery, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

I use PhpStorm and it is giving me warnings when I define a parameter as a type jQuery with JSDoc.

I've tried to configure jQuery as a library, but it didn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * @param {jQuery} $button
 */
function setActive($button)
{
    // The code is working fine, but PhpStorm is giving the warning 
    // "Unresolved function or method addClass()" here.
    $button.addClass("active");

    // If I try to do this, no warning is displayed.
    $("#test").addClass("test");
}
```

**EDIT:**

Some methods appear in the intellisense (I'm not sure why), but unfortunately `addClass` isn't one of them.

[image]

Comment: That's odd. It recognizes the parameter as jQuery for me.

Comment: @Phiter Do you have any special configuration in your PHPStorm? It seems correct, but I just can't get rid of this warning.

Comment: Nothing special. If you use `$('body').` will it autocomplete with jQuery functions?

Comment: Take a look: https://imgur.com/a/d1Cxo

Comment: Yes, it works with anything inside $(). It doesn't work only with the parameter.

Comment: You can also write `$($button).addClass();` Have you added jQuery as a library? Does it include non-minified version of it?

Comment: @LazyOne I haven't thought of write `$($button).addClass()`. It works, although it looks strange. I've added jQuery as a library through the Download button inside PhpStorm, I don't really know what version it includes.

Comment: A screenshots of a library definition would be good. I'll be honest: I have not tried it now (in current version) .. but last time I've used such typehint (approx a year ago) it worked fine for me -- I saw no such warnings on any of the jQuery methods & code completion was working for the methods I've used then.

Comment: @LazyOne Yeah, I'm starting to think I'm doing something really stupid, but I can't figure it out. The weirdest thing is that it works with anything except when I pass it as a parameter. I've added jQuery as a library with a non-minified version, but it didn't solve it. I'll left the question open for a while and, if nothing changes, I'll go with your suggestion `$($button).addClass()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding JQuery typings (either via **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**, **TypeScript Community Stubs** or by running `npm i @types/jquery` in project dir) - this should solve the issue:

[image]

Comment: Wow, it works, but I had to put an uppercase J in JQuery. Is it the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the Typescript for jQuery uses an Uppercase J so `JQuery` instead of `jQuery`.

Changing the jsdoc like so fixes this issue.

```
/**
 * @param {JQuery} $button
 */
```

Otherwise the lowercase `jQuery` may be enabled by creating a very simple typescript file somewhere in your project.

For example your file could be named `jquery.d.ts` and have the following content.

```
/**
 * Must have the @types/jquery typescript installed
 * either via PHPStorm -> Javascript -> Libraries
 * or `npm i @types/jquery`
 */
interface jQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> extends JQuery {}
```